# Why do I get Detached Entity exception when upgrading Spring Boot 1.1.4 to 1.1.5

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot

On updating Spring Boot from 1.1.4 to 1.1.5 a simple web application started generating detached entity exceptions. Specifically, a post authentication inteceptor that bumped number of visits was causing the problem.

A quick check of loaded dependencies showed that Spring Data has been updated from 1.6.1 to 1.6.2 and a further check of the change log shows a couple of issues relating to optimistic locking, version fields and JPA issues that have been fixed.

Well I am using a version field and it starts out as Null following recommendation to not set in the specification.

I have produced a very simple test scenario where I get detached entity exceptions if the version field starts as null or zero. If I create an entity with version 1 however then I do not get these exceptions.

Is this expected behaviour or is there still something amiss?

Below is the test scenario I have for this condition. In the scenario the service layer that has been annotated @Transactional. Each test case makes multiple calls to the service layer - the tests are working with detached entities as this is the scenario I am working with in the full blown application.

The test case comprises four tests:

**Test 1 - versionNullCausesAnExceptionOnUpdate()**

In this test the version field in the detached object is Null. This is how I would usually create the object prior to passing to the service.

This test fails with a Detached Entity exception.

I would have expected this test to pass. If there is a flaw in the test then the rest of the scenario is probably moot.

**Test 2 - versionZeroCausesExceptionOnUpdate()**

In this test I have set the version to value Long(0L). This is an edge case test and included because I found reference to Zero values being used for version field in the Spring Data change log.

This test fails with a Detached Entity exception.

Of interest simply because the following two tests pass leaving this as an anomaly.

**Test 3 - versionOneDoesNotCausesExceptionOnUpdate()**

In this test the version field is set to value Long(1L). Not something I would usually do, but considering the notes in the Spring Data change log I decided to give it a go.

This test passes.

Would not usually set the version field, but this looks like a work-around until I figure out why the first test is failing.

**Test 4 - versionOneDoesNotCausesExceptionWithMultipleUpdates()**

Encouraged by the result of test 3 I pushed the scenario a step further and perform multiple updates on the entity that started life with a version of Long(1L).

This test passes.

Reinforcement that this may be a useable work-around.

**The entity:**

```
package com.mvmlabs.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name="user_details")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer numberOfVisits;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfVisits() {
        return numberOfVisits == null ? 0 : numberOfVisits;
    }

    public void setNumberOfVisits(Integer numberOfVisits) {
        this.numberOfVisits = numberOfVisits;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**The repository:**

```
package com.mvmlabs.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.mvmlabs.domain.User;

public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

**The service interface:**

```
package com.mvmlabs.service;

import com.mvmlabs.domain.User;

public interface UserService {
    User save(User user);
    User loadUser(Long id);
    User registerVisit(User user);
}
```

**The service implementation:**

```
package com.mvmlabs.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import com.mvmlabs.dao.UserDao;
import com.mvmlabs.domain.User;

@Service
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public class UserServiceJpaImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public User loadUser(Long id) {
        return userDao.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User registerVisit(User user) {
        user.setNumberOfVisits(user.getNumberOfVisits() + 1);
        return userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return userDao.save(user);
    }
}
```

**The application class:**

```
package com.mvmlabs;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**The POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mvmlabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-issue</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-jpa-issue</name>
    <description>JPA Issue between spring boot 1.1.4 and 1.1.5</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.mvmlabs.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**The application properties:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database: HSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql: true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:./target/testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

**The test case:**

```
package com.mvmlabs;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.mvmlabs.domain.User;
import com.mvmlabs.service.UserService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void versionNullCausesAnExceptionOnUpdate() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("Version Null");
        user.setNumberOfVisits(0);
        user.setVersion(null);
        user = userService.save(user);
        user = userService.registerVisit(user);

        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(1), user.getNumberOfVisits());
        Assert.assertEquals(new Long(1L), user.getVersion());
    }

    @Test
    public void versionZeroCausesExceptionOnUpdate() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("Version Zero");
        user.setNumberOfVisits(0);
        user.setVersion(0L);
        user = userService.save(user);
        user = userService.registerVisit(user);

        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(1), user.getNumberOfVisits());
        Assert.assertEquals(new Long(1L), user.getVersion());
    }

    @Test
    public void versionOneDoesNotCausesExceptionOnUpdate() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("Version One");
        user.setNumberOfVisits(0);
        user.setVersion(1L);
        user = userService.save(user);
        user = userService.registerVisit(user);

        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(1), user.getNumberOfVisits());
        Assert.assertEquals(new Long(2L), user.getVersion());
    }


    @Test
    public void versionOneDoesNotCausesExceptionWithMultipleUpdates() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("Version One Multiple");
        user.setNumberOfVisits(0);
        user.setVersion(1L);
        user = userService.save(user);

        user = userService.registerVisit(user);
        user = userService.registerVisit(user);
        user = userService.registerVisit(user);

        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(3), user.getNumberOfVisits());
        Assert.assertEquals(new Long(4L), user.getVersion());
    }
}
```

The first two tests fail with detached entity exception. The last two tests pass as expected.

Now change Spring Boot version to 1.1.4 and rerun, all tests pass.

Are my expectations wrong?

Edit: This code saved to GitHub at https://github.com/mmeany/spring-boot-detached-entity-issue

Comment: Not sure why it runs with 1.1.4 but I would actually expect it to fail. Basically what you see now is correct. Your test method isn't transactional so the `save` method operates in its own transaction. After that the entity is detached, the `registerVisit` now operates on a detached entity. I would expect it to work if you reload the entity in your `registerVisit` method or make your test method transactional.

Comment: The service is annotated @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false). I do not want the transaction at the test level, but specifically at the service level. The database will be recreated each run so this is not an issue here.

Comment: To be fair I experimented with transactions as well. The code in the GitHub repo actually has some debug in that I did not want polluting the post here and this checks that a transaction is active in the service layer.

Comment: It is an issue as as soon as the transaction is over the `Session` (or `EntityManager` is also closed. The whole point is that `save`  and `registerVisit` operate on different transactions and thus sessions. That is the whole point of the problem.

Comment: I agree with your comment that the two operations take place in separate transactions. But spring data repository save() method should invoke merge() on entity manager for a detached entity. Have I missinterpreted this? It certainly appears that this is how the two tests are behaving when a version field of value 1 is used, though this could be by chance. I appreciate your time and am not trying to be argumentative, just searching for the reason.

Comment: Why are you messing around with the version field btw? That is something you shouldn't do manually. I suspect that after the initial save your `version` is still `null`, which makes Spring Data JPA think it is new and then it will call `persist` instead of `merge`. Or the other way around, whilst setting the version, it detects it as not new leading to a `merge` (which doesn't transfer the id) .

Comment: The first test, what I would consider a normal operation, I am not messing with the version. The version is Null. The test fails. The second test demonstrates the same issue with a Zero version. Subsequent tests demonstrate that messing with the version and setting it to 1L works, as I stated in the question this is not what I would usually do as it is not in accordance with the standard. I will update the question with a more comprehensive explanation of the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with spring-data-jpa in release 1.6.2, this has been resolved in the spring-data-jpa 1.6.4-RELEASE. As soon as a Spring Boot update pulls in the new version of spring data JPA this will become a non-issue, until then override the version of spring-data-jpa in the POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Adding this to the test case fixes all issues, all tests pass as expected.